# Apache Shiro takes me back to login page after authentication

Tags: shiro

I am replacing Siteminder with Apache Shiro in my web application. I noticed that shiro logs me in successfully and takes me to the home page. When i click on any other link on the home page, I am taken back to the login page. I login again and i am forwarded to the page i was looking to goto. How can i fix this?

Here is my shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
ssl.enabled=false

[users]
user=admin

[urls]
/css/** = anon
/images/** = anon
/js/** = anon
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

A section from my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>       
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>      
</filter-mapping>
```

Printing out currentUser.isAuthenticated() in my User Class displays 'true'.

Is there any other info i can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. My application was deployed on Weblogic and i had the following section inside weblogic.xml which was causing the issue. Removing it, fixed it. Any idea why this caused it?

```
<session-param>     
<param-name>CookieSecure</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</session-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!  Hopefully this will help other WebLogic users in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is related to the fact that in the shiro.ini file you are not enforcing SSL:

```
ssl.enabled=false
```

However, in the weblogic.xml file you are enforcing SSL for cookies:

```
<session-param>     
<param-name>CookieSecure</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</session-param>
```

So, my recommendation would be to change shiro.ini to:

`ssl.enabled=true`

And leave the original weblogic.xml file in place.

That way you will only accept users who authenticated over SSL (which is a good practice).

Please let me know the results.

Thanks
Fabio @fcerullo

Comment: In DEV we do not use SSL. We've enabled SSL in UAT and Production only. I think your answer makes sense. I'll test it out when we move to our SSL enabled environment. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, please let me know the results. Also, could you please vote for me if it solves your issue? Thanks again, Fabio

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks almost exactly like the [Shiro sample web app](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/samples/web/) (in fact, yours is even better by using authc.loginUrl instead of the deprecated global 'shiro.loginUrl' that the sample app uses).  The sample app does not exhibit the behavior you're seeing.

This leads me to believe that something else (another filter?) is causing problems for you.  Do you have a little sample app that you can make available (maybe on Github) that demonstrates the problem?  I'd be happy to take a look if this can be recreated.

Comment: I created a bare bones version of the application and it worked fine. I will have to now find what in my application is causing this. I did not change anything in my existing web.xml or struts-config.xml. I'll report back when i figure out what went wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: I figured out what was going on. My application was deployed on Weblogic and i had the following section inside weblogic.xml which was causing the issue. Removing it, fixed it. Any idea why this caused it? 
      ' <session-param>     
  <param-name>CookieSecure</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
        </session-param> '

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same behaviour,but I am using Wildfly 10.0.0 , and apache shiro v 1.3.2.

I foun the solution here in [this Jboss Forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243192) article.

Setting the cookie name from `JSESSIONID` to something else fixes the issue.

The solution provided here was to add the following in shiro.ini

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = shiro.session.id
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
```

This worked for me.